# C++0x and Friend functions and boost::make_shared

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, friend, make-shared

If I have a class with a private construction, using `boost::make_shared()` to construct a `shared_ptr` of that class from within a member function of that class will issue a compiler error using gcc 4.6.

```
#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"
#include "boost/make_shared.hpp"

class Foo
{
private:
    Foo(int a){};
public:
    static boost::shared_ptr<Foo> do_foo(){ return boost::make_shared<Foo>(5); }
    friend template boost::shared_ptr<Foo> boost::make_shared<Foo>( Arg1 && arg1, Args && ... args );
}

int main()
{
    auto f = Foo::do_foo();
}
```

A call to `Foo::do_foo` will result in a compiler error.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not specified which function actually calls the constructor in `make_shared`, so you cannot make that function a friend. If you have a class with a private constructor like this then you thus cannot construct an instance with `make_shared`.

However, what you can do is create a derived class with a public constructor that calls the appropriate base class constructor, and make that derived class a friend (so it can call the private constructor):

```
class Foo
{
private:  
    Foo(int a){};  
public:  
    static boost::shared_ptr do_foo();
    friend class DerivedFoo;
};

class DerivedFoo: public Foo
{
public:
    DerivedFoo(int a):
        Foo(a)
    {}
};

boost::shared_ptr<Foo> Foo::do_foo(){ return boost::make_shared<DerivedFoo>(5); }
```

If `DerivedFoo` is in an anonymous namespace in the .cpp file that defines `do_foo` then functions in other .cpp files will still not be able to construct any instances of `Foo` directly, and users will not be able to tell that what they have is actually a `DerivedFoo`.

Answer (score 0):

You need, at the very least, to provide template arguments in a few places.

```
class Foo  
{  
private:  
    Foo(int a){};  
public:  
    static boost::shared_ptr<Foo> do_foo(){ return boost::make_shared<Foo>(5); }
    friend template boost::shared_ptr<Foo> boost::make_shared<Foo>( Arg1 && arg1, Args && ... args );
}
```

Comment: @sellibitze Probably shouldn't be there, but I just copy-pasted the OP's code. `make_shared` does take variable number of arguments, and it passes them on to the target type's constructor.